# Print lines that contain a string only once

Tags: linux, grep, command, uniq

For example this is my file called `Weapons`:

```
Sword of Dragons
Staff of Fire
Bow of Noxious
Staff of Light
Bow of Noxious
```

I want to type in a command that will display lines containing `Bow` only once.

Here is what I tried:

```
grep -n "Bow" Weapons
```

But it only displays all lines that contain `Bow`. How do I only display a line that contains `Bow` just once?

Comment: so you want lines in which `Bow` appears just once, right?

Comment: Yes I only need it to display a line that contains `Bow` just once.

Comment: OK. By the way you were placing "once" it could also be understood as "print a line that contains 'Bow' and do it just once per file". Now it is clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Bow` as field separator in `awk` and just print if this leads to 2 fields in a line:

```
awk -F"Bow" 'NF==2' file
```

And use `IGNORECASE=1` if you want it not to be case dependent.

To match the exact word (`Bow` but not `bowtie`, for example), you can use with GNU awk, thanks to Ed Morton's suggestion, the `<` `>` anchors to indicate the limits of the word (like `\b` in other languages):

```
awk -F'\\<Bow\\>' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} NF==2' a
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Sword of Dragons
Staff of Fire
Bow of Noxious
Staff of Light
Bow I like Bow
this is a bow
and this a bowtie
$ awk -F"Bow" 'NF==2' a
Bow of Noxious
$ awk -F"Bow" 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} NF==2' a
Bow of Noxious
this is a bow
and this a bowtie
$ awk -F'\\<Bow\\>' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} NF==2' a
Bow of Noxious
this is a bow
```

Comment: I like your style :-)

Comment: will fail if file contains "Bowler", etc. You could use `-F'\\<Bow\\>'` with GNU awk.

Answer (score 2):

You can use build in option in the sort command:

```
sort -u file | grep -i bow
```

or if you insist on using unique

```
sort file | uniq  | grep -i bow
```

Comment: will fail if file contains "Bowler", etc.

Comment: He did not ask for the word, but if you want it the grep part will be: `grep -oh "\w*Bow\w*" *`

Comment: That will still fail. The point is when looking for the word "Bow" you almost certainly don't want to match other words that just happen to contain the word Bow, eg. Bowler.